# How to recreate this Emboss effect on a letter?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

[image]

How can I recreate this exact emboss effect on Photoshop? I tried this a couple of times, my attempt is on the second attachment. I have issues with separating the bevel shadows. Thanks! [image]

Comment: 'Bevel and Emboss' is a Photoshop Layer Effect that can get you pretty close to the above effect. How did you achieve yours?

Comment: like i said, I haven't managed to get it where I wanted it to be on the second example, and tried for a couple of hours and hence im asking here haha

Comment: Looks like you are already 95% of the way there. Add a drop shadow to complete it.

Comment: Bevel & emboss in Pshop is actually a pretty simplistic set of functions these days. It's entirely 'number of pixels' based, so often you can get dramatically different effects by changing your image/font size . I'd at least try your existing version at a size more comparable to the one you're trying to copy.